# Optimised Images Taking A Long Time To Load When Fetched From MySQL Database (via PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, load

I have some responsive images that are being outputted onto a page where the URLs come from filenames stored in a MySQL database. The images, although optimised (even the large versions are < 200KB), always take 5.00s to load.

The code is below, at this stage there are only 6 images in the database for testing, but I can't work out why this kills the page-load speed. When I remove the images or add in a static image taken from a site folder and type the path manually this issue doesn't happen.

The `$filename` is a taken from a URL parameter on the page and the details then fetched from the MySQL database with PHP.

The images are produced at 3 different sizes when uploaded with the Imagick PHP library (500,750 and 1000px) and the sizes added via string concatenation.

The problem may be being caused by the MySQL database itself on MAMP, but as well as looking into that I thought I'd better check I'm not doing something completely wrong here (I'm relatively new to PHP/MySQL and web development generally).

```
<?php

isset($_GET['filename']) ? $filename = $_GET['filename'] : header("Location: login.php");

$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM imageposts WHERE filename = :filename");

$stmt->execute([
':filename' => $filename
]); 

$www_root = "http://localhost:8888/site";

$db_image_filename = htmlspecialchars($row['filename']);
$db_image_ext = htmlspecialchars($row['file_extension']);
$db_image_title = htmlspecialchars($row['image_title']);

?>

// image output

<img
src="<?php echo $www_root . '/images-lib/' . $db_image_filename . '-500' . '.' . $db_ext; ?>"
srcset="<?php echo $www_root . '/images-lib/' . $db_image_filename . '-500' . '.' . $db_ext; ?> 500w,
        <?php echo $www_root . '/images-lib/' . $db_image_filename . '-750' . '.' . $db_ext; ?> 750w"
alt="<?php echo $db_image_title; ?>" 
title="<?php echo $db_image_title; ?>"
>
```

**Note:** a typical filename is `614b66956a121_1632331413-500` which is generated via the Imagick library when the image is uploaded, and `$db_ext` is either `.jpeg` or `.png`

Image below showing the 5 seconds for image load.

[image: Network tab showing image load time]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of timings. If you use chrome press F12, go to networking tab and hit F5

Comment: hi @Daniels118 in the network tab it is always exactly 5.00s for images everything else is as you'd expect. Will post an image though.

Comment: include skip-name-resolve as a database setting in the MySQL configuration

Comment: Can you post the generated html page?

Comment: @Daniels118 I've just stripped all the other HTML out apart from the boilerplate HTML, head and body tags and it's still happening, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: hi @danblack do you know how I would do that on phpMyAdmin/MAMP ?

Comment: But can you try to copy the generated html and put it in a simple html file and check if the problem persists?

Comment: @Daniels118 I mention that in the question.

Comment: You said you typed the path manually, so there is no warranty you typed exactly what your script is printing. I know this is annoing, but trying what I said above is the only way to be sure (there could be non printable characters and other hidden things).
Other observations:
- in the code shown you are using "$row" but you haven't assigned it;
- the img tag should be self closed: <img ... />
- in the network tab hover the mouse over the blue bar next to "5.00 s" and post a screenshot of the timing drill-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted MAMP about this because I noticed these types of questions about MAMP were getting more comments and upvotes etc. It was a problem their end with MAMP 6.5 which they managed to fix and it was updated in MAMP 6.6. This resolved the issues.